# FPS problen in GrSim

Tags: c++, ode-library

When i run grsim, fps is about 1!
also after put robots or ball,they disappear when touch ground.
i use Fedora 20 and tried install ODE with yum.
problem is this:

> ODE Message 2: mass must be > 0 in dMassCheck() [mass.cpp:49]
>
> ODE Message 2: mass must be > 0 in dMassCheck() [mass.cpp:49]
>
> ODE INTERNAL ERROR 1: assertion "dMassCheck(mass)" failed in dBodySetMass() [ode.cpp:495]
> Aborted (core dumped)

after a lot search, i found that the solutions are compile ODE, change some codes(in ODEMath.h) and some other.
so i recompiled some changed codes and at last grsim lunched(with FPS and robots disappear problem)

with

```
optirun glxgears
```

results ,i have no problem in graphic card(output fps is about 60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve this problem ,i just updated fedora 20 to fedora 21. may some package update helped me. problem wasn't graphic driver surly!

Answer (score 0):

I compiled ODE from source without any customizations and it gave me the same problem until I added `-DdSINGLE` to my compiler flags. Apparently ODE requires you to specify the type of dReal with `dDOUBLE` for double precision or `dSINGLE` for single precision and somehow when `dDOUBLE` is defined, there is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

For **Visual Studio 2019** "Project Properties -> Configoration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions -> add 'dIDEDOUBLE' " it worked for me.